# Can I run two sets of 10/3 30amp wire to feed one panel?

Tags: subpanel, shed

I have a shed that I want to supply power too.  Can I run 2 sets of 10/3 30amp cable to one panel? Or does each cable have to have its own panel?

Approximate wire length will be 45 foot.  I already have the 10/3 wire on hand.  I hope to get a small welder and want to make sure I have enough power to operate it.

Comment: How large is this shed, and can you provide us with information about the amp rating of the welder you're looking at? (I1eff/I1max)

Comment: And run your cable in properly buried conduit. It's a bit more expensive up front, but the trench can be shallower so the digging is easier. If there's _ever_ a reason to run new wiring, you just pull the old stuff out of the conduit and pull the new stuff through. Presto, you're done, no need to dig again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. It is called paralleling, and it is prohibited except in very limited circumstances, which don't apply here.

Think about it this way:

- 60A breaker in main panel
- 2 x 10/3 cable - doubled up. Sufficient to handle 60A (30A per cable).
- **One hot wire in one cable breaks** (loose connection, rats, whatever)

Now you have:

- 60A on two parallel hots from one side of the breaker - OK
- 60A on two parallel neutrals - OK
- 60A on **one** 10 AWG hot from the other side of the breaker **burning down your house and/or shed**.

Figure out the total power requirements (i.e., what other lights and equipment might be running at the same time as the welder) and put in a single feed (larger than 10 AWG, size based on max. current, possibly aluminum wires instead of copper) to a subpanel and connect the welder and everything else to that panel with appropriately sized wire (can't parallel main to subpanel or subpanel to equipment).

Answer (score 6):

### That's a violation two ways.

First, you can't *parallel*.  Paralleling requires special equipment *rated for paralleling* on the supply end - this is for a bunch of reasons.   It is also not allowed below a fairly large wire size.  It's also uneconomical below an *even larger* wire size, and as a result, nobody makes paralleling equipment except for really huge wire.   NEC 310.10.

Second, you can only have one supply feed to a building.  NEC 225.30.

Bonus violation: Can't use NM cable outdoors, not even in conduit.  (especially not in smallish conduit!)

### Anyway, it sounds like this is about economics.

Here's a fact nobody knows: **10/3 UF and 2-2-2-4 MH feeder are about the same price**, even though one is 30A and the other is 90A.

Use 2-2-2-4 MH feeder.  Save the valuable 10/3 for something that actually needs 10/3, like ... .... a dryer, or range/oven separates, or *shrug* TWO travel trailers?  Sell it on Craigslist?

60A breakers are 1/3 the price of 90A breakers, so go ahead and breaker it at 60A if you want to pinch pennies there.  If you ever develop the need for 90A, you can change the breaker to that, then. Use the cost savings on a nicer subpanel, because "number of breaker spaces" is one place *never* to scrimp!  A 24-space is not excessive, and nice thing, the combo packs come with a bunch of breakers!

You'll need a subpanel anyway, since you can't put #2 wire directly on a receptacle, and a subpanel is the cheapest possible way to get 4 lugs to adapt #2 down to smaller wires.

MH feeder is aluminum, but that's perfectly fine for large feeders like that.  (which is funny because you never expected to use a large feeder, eh? :)

Answer (score 4):

I am in this situation with a kitchen remodel. Kitchen originally had two separate Aluminum 6/3 wires running to it - one for stove and one for an oven I believe. Needed to use them to feed 6 new circuits.

Instead of paralleling (using two separate feeder wires) into one sub panel, I decided to install two separate subpanels next to each other instead. Each feeder wire will get its on subpanel.

Comment: This is a great solution.